# PHP recursive function to sort all sub categories

Tags: php

I have a table of categories, each category has a sub-category, and that sub-category can have infinite amount of sub categories.
The table 3 columns: CategoryID, ParentCategoryID, Name
So lets say I have this this structure:

```
-Clothes
  -Top
    -Shirt
    -Sweater
    -Hate
  -Bottom
    -Pants
    -Socks
-Tech
  -Hardware
    -Computers
    -phones
  -Software
    -photo editing
    -browsers
```

What I want to do is associate the last sub-category in the tree to the main category, so the main categories would be Clothes and Tech.
An example would be something like:

```
array("Socks" => "Clothes", "Phones" => "Tech")
```

So to sum it up. All I want is to match the subcategory ID to the main top category ID

I'm doing this in PHP.
Thanks

Comment: you need to show what you have attempted to do.

Comment: vote up for @cmorrissey, but let this question live even without the attempt `code`, it is quite a nice/interesting problem, good one to have on SO. it would also be nice to do this directly from SQL

Comment: @cobarzan, it isn't defined accurately? `socks to clothes` then should it be `browsers to Tech` by the same rule? There needs to be another list supplied to solve this problem reliably?

Comment: @RyanVincent well the rule is more vague than that. I can have 100 subcategories but the problem is that a sub-category only has the parent-category-ID ... meaning that the 100th sub category will not know what it's main category is because it's not defined in the database. I'm trying to find a way to associate those two with a function.